How to list all available revisions on the snap store
The docs suggests the snap store caches previous revisions, as well as 2 revisions locally. I'm in need to control what revision gets installed and what revision to update to (after testing the target revision).
I'm not seeing how to list all revisions for the stable channel for chromium snap. It just gives me the most available and a list of other channels, beta, edge etc. I'm only interested in listing all available revisions on the snap store.
https://snapcraft.io/docs/revisions

Revision package management
The Snap Store caches several older revisions of every snap, as does
the local system. By default, 2 revisions are stored locally, while
Ubuntu Core systems store 3. These defaults can be changed with the
refresh-retain system option.


"need to control what revision gets installed and what revision to update to" suggests the need to track the current and future revision numbers (today's chromium stable is rev 2846). It's unclear why tracking that rev number requires a list of all 2846 revisions (and growing) stored on the snap-store servers. Perhaps you might edit the question to clarify?

https://snapcraft.io/docs/release-management

The information is bit misleading, as not the snap-store does the revision management, but snapd does that itself. The snap-store just reads information from there.
To see all current snaps present on the system, open a terminal and execute:
snap list --all

The standard setting of snap on desktop systems is that always two revisions per snap are kept: the current one and the previously installed one. This cannot be changed to one revision only, but it can be increase to more than two revisions. The command
sudo snap set system refresh.retain=3 

would increase the revisions to be kept to 3.
snap can revert to any previous version of a snap which is still on your system. The command to run is:
sudo snap revert NAME_OF_THE_SNAP

to revert to the previous revision. If you need to revert to an older revision than the previous one (as said, still has to be on your system!), the command to run is
sudo snap revert --revision=REVISIONSNUMBER NAME_OF_THE_SNAP `

where REVISIONNUMBER can be found in the out of of the command snap list --all.
snap, and thus the snap-store, do not support to install older / historic versions from the snapcraft.io. So there is no command to pull and install a version of a snap which was the current version e.g. 3 month or 1 year or so ago. So in case you may have the need to return for whatever reason to an older version of the snap, released previous to the previous one, it is recommendable to keep more than one previous revision on your system. snap, and thus the snap-store, can only install the current version from each channel available of a given snap.
